# Safe to put nail into drywall when stud finder finds "live voltage"?

Tags: electrical, drywall

I'm trying to hang a calendar on the drywall. 
Tried 3M small Command hook, but it falls off after a few days.
Now I'm considering to use a nail or a drywall hook like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GPM2VXK).

I used a stud finder with live voltage detection feature (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HTFHOEI)), and I found that a pretty broad area near where I want to put calendar may have live AC voltage.

I did some Google search. Someone suggested to ignore it if a short nail or drywall hook is used, since it's very unlikely to damage the wire.

So my questions are:

- Is it safe to put nail into the drywall in this case? Should I worry about the live voltage reported by the stud finder?
- Any other recommendation for simply hanging a calendar? (I'll probably try a larger adhesive hook first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nail isn't exactly safe if you are directly nailing.   Chances of something happening are small (and really much greater chance to damage line than "shock" yourself) but it is there.   Also I doubt a nail would hang the calendar without eventually sagging.   Calendars are touched and moved and not ideal for just a nail - unless you can get that nail in framing.

Monkey hooks should be about as safe as it gets.   Don't hit them or press them in.   Screw them in slowly (I know there isn't threads) and once you pierce the drywall loosely move the main shaft up.  If you aren't applying pressure to it once it is in even if it hit a line it should not nick or pierce it.   I would go this route if you have to have the calendar in this exact location.   Monkey hooks are very strong and not invasive to your walls.

If you want to be extra safe with Monkey hooks you can bend the tip so it isn't sharp on the end once you get through the wall.

Answer (score 1):

The wire should be 1-1/4" behind the face of the stud if done to code. It is also possible the wire is running down the stud in that case it would be on the side.

Answer (score 1):

I had a stud finder simular to yours and it showed me electrical wires in places I knew there weren't any. 
I bought a new one and invested a little more money and now it works just fine. 
I would stay away from any wires/ pipes if you can. It's not worth the aftermath and you never know if the previous owner/ contractor stuck to the code!